# Suppose that there exists a square matrix such that the first $m$ columns of $BA$ is Im . Show that $A_x = (1 2 ... m)$ has solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an m×n matrix whereby $m \le n$. Suppose that there exists a square matrix B of order m such that the first m columns of $BA$ is $I_m$ . Show that $A_x = \begin{pmatrix}1 2 \cdots m\end{pmatrix}$ has solutions.

I am clueless on how to approach this question. Would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Start by multiplying both sides, on the left, by $B$. What do you get?

Comment: Can you show that $\begin{pmatrix}Ae_1&...&Ae_m\\| & ...&|\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is invertible? What does this suggest about the first $m$ columns of $A$?